# Spring boot maven project has to be updated everytime to see a change ECLIPSE IDE

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using thymeleaf with spring boot my `index.html` is located in `src/main/resources/template` every time I want to see a change I have to stop the server, update the project, and rerun the application, this is highly ineffeciant, I just want to run and refresh, I added `devtools` to my dependencies and also set `spring.thymeleaf.cache= false` and it still does not work

Comment: Which IDEA you are using?

Comment: eclipse is my ide

Comment: look at this: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/614

Answer (score 1):

Edit the starter dependencies and add the devtools option, that way it will restart everytime you make changes.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-application-live-reload-hot-swap-with you should edit registry if you are using Intellij.

> 1. Open the Settings --> Build-Execution-Deployment --> Compiler
>
>    and enable the Make Project Automatically.
> 2. Then press ctrl+shift+A and search for the registry. In the registry, make the 
>      following configuration enabled.
>
> `compiler.automake.allow.when.app.running`
>
> 3. Restart the IDE.

Comment: could you please provide the solution for eclipse, I still have not found the answer

Answer (score 0):

One of the main challenge for the java developers is to deploy the apps and restart server when ever there is a code change.we can reload the code changes without having to restart the server. In Spring Boot this can be achieved by adding a DevTools module, just add the following dependency in your Spring Boots pom.xml and build it.

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
     <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

Spring Boot DevTools module does exactly what developers needed, this eliminates the process of manually deploying the changes. DevTools will auto restart the server when we have changes. Spring team they haven’t included this feature in Spring Boot’s initial version, upon several request they added this feature later.